# C/C++ equivalent for C# System.Net.Mail

Tags: c++, c, email, smtp

I have sent emails from windows using C# programming [like this](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-smtp-mail.htm). It is really an easy thing to do. However I have shifted to programming on linux a while ago and want some kind of equivalent for C/C++.

I have been searching all the web and I can't find any library. All i find is application that I need to install and run. Is there any such library on C/C++ that can be used as easily?

Thanks for your input :)

Comment: Or you could use Mono to compile and execute C# code on Linux.

Comment: [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) supports SMTP and SMTPS

Comment: I don't know if there exists a decent library, but, the last time I attempted this, I read the SMTP protocol specification and use C/C++ socket library.

Comment: I wish I can, I am at university and can't install on the system. So I am stuck with using what is already there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of candidates show up when googling "C SMTP library", including a reference to this very bare-bones bit of code here on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210/c-smtp-example

Comment: do you know how I can alter it to use gmail?

Comment: Try an open-source library that supported secure SMTP, e.g. http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.SecureSMTPClientSession.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather simple way to send an email from a C/C++ program on Linux. It's doesn't use a library and maybe it's not what you wanted, but it's quite simple if your needs are simple.

```
char cmd[] = "mail -s \"Hello world\" you@youremailid.com < /home/jrn/email.txt";
system(cmd);
```